# Can you disable autohide animation in Visual Studio docking?

Tags: visual-studio

When you dock a window to the side of visual studio, it can auto hide.  When it does this, it animates open or closed.  Is it possible to disable this animation so it just shows or hides to the correct size?  It's slow over remote desktop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

tools->Environment->general->Animate environment tools (check box)

Answer (score 6):

1. tools > Options
2. environment > General
3. uncheck Animate Enviornment Tools